# Рассылка писем на голом PHP, как ускорить скрипт?

Tags: email, рассылка, php, exim

На сайте есть необходимость рассылать пользователям персональные уведомления на почту о каких-то событиях. На некоторые события подписано уже более 3000 пользователей.

Скрипт работает по крону, берет задание из БД, формирует шаблон письма, затем выбирает из БД (MySQL) список адресатов и в цикле подставляет в шаблон MemberName, MemberMail и отправляет банальным mail(). Письма небольшие (< 1 Кб) без вложений. Дальше письмами занимается exim.

Проблема в том, что рассылка занимает весьма значительное время (именно выполнение указанного php-скрипта). Например:
421 письмо - 37.764 с.
858 писем - 95.971 с.
1337 писем - 217.12 с.
1607 писем - 301.72 с.

Понятно, что можно переделать очередь и рассылать по 100 писем или там по 200, но вопрос в другом - такое время выполнения подобного скрипта это нормально? Можно ли скрипт принципиально оптимизировать?

Сайт крутится на сервере от Hezner (Intel® Core™ i7-2600, 16 GB DDR3).

Comment: Для начала можно попробовать распараллелить рассылку (на локальный MTA). Разложить отправляемую пачку писем в десяток оглавлений (количество подбирается экспериментально) и на каждое оглавление запустить свой процесс отправки (делать fork).

Если не поможет, то придется программировать отправку через ESMTP и  делать ее в каждом процессе. 

И (в первую очередь) надо посмотреть (изучить) настройки exim (конкретно в нем я не разбираюсь), чтобы понять, почему у Вас скорость падает от количества писем  (из Ваших замеров -- 11, 9, 6, 5 писем в секунду)

Comment: делал рассылку для сайта онлайн-игрульки, - использовал прямое обращение на 25 порт через curl, 10к писем уходило за минуту-полторы, параметры серевера раза в три хуже

Comment: deivan_ кстате да, ты открывал так называемый поток, но тратил трафик... Жаль что в php не реализованы потоки...

Comment: Ссылки из ответов: http://profyclub.ru/docs/297 http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=email&page=007

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать очереди. Можно посмотреть доклад на эту тему: [Впервые в рунете: сказ о 100М писем в день](http://profyclub.ru/docs/297)

Comment: Остается повторить комментарий в конце Вашей ссылки

    Отличный доклад.

От себя добавлю, на редкость профессиональная статья о почтовой системе. Всем советую ознакомиться.

Comment: Большое спасибо конечно за вашу статью! ну я думаю, что лучше будет использовать специальные сервисы, напрмиер Unisender

Comment: доклад ни о чем "менеджер румяным .... по стенам"

Answer (score -1):

Хм mail() помню проблемы с ним, он вечно создает новое соединение а потом его закрывает,нагружает сервер, попробуйте сокет, общатся с email сервером через SMTP, вот пример http://i-leon.ru/smtp-php/ если конечноже хостинг позволит...

Answer (score -2):

Функция mail() при каждом вызове создаёт новое подключение к smtp серверу. Так что скорость с ней улучшить не получиться. Как вариант использовать решение описанное в данной [статье](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=email&page=007) . Расписан вариант с отправкой большого количества писем за одно соединение.

Comment: mail() может и локальный sendmail вызывать который в очередь письмо из stdin складывает.